# Origin of gerrymandering phrase regarding politicians picking voters

Tags: history, gerrymandering, rhetoric

Recently, I had a project involving studying the history of ***redistricting*** and ***gerrymandering***.

In my studies, I came across what appears to be a particularly common aphorism in redistricting academia. It generally takes the approximate form of **“gerrymandering means that it’s not the voters picking their representatives; it’s the representatives picking their voters!”**

**I was curious as to when and where this phrase originated**, due to its ubiquity in its particular niche.

However, I was unable to find any research dating the phrase, and a somewhat exhaustive Google search (done by moving the latest search point further into the past) turned up as the oldest source I could find: [a FairVote article from early 2001](http://archive.fairvote.org/library/history/flores/backgrnd.htm) that says that with at-large elections, “[p]oliticians are not permitted to choose the voters, and the evils of gerrymandering are conveniently avoided...”

However, this answer is not definitive by any means, and I would like a more definitive answer than “Google says so”. **So, can anyone help me find the origin of this quote? Anything would be helpful.**

By the way, if this question seems a bit out of place here, I would like to note that I already put it on English Stack Exchange. A user effectively stated that the question was out of place there because it mentioned something political. I disagreed, but arguing the point didn't seem worth it to me.

**(Note, I am not seeking the origin of the word "gerrymander", I am well aware of that.)**

Comment: I have no idea what the answer is, and I would have expected it to be on topic at English.SE, but it's certainly on topic here.

Comment: Good thing I re-read. At first I thought you were asking for the origin of the word "gerrymandering."

Comment: You and everybody on English.SE.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp I am a regular contributor on English Language Users, more so than I am here. And I can see why you may have been having problems. Clearly it doesn't belong there but here on Politics. I have broken the text up into paragraphs and highlighted key aspects. Hopefully that should prevent people like me misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I have also upvoted it as a very worthwhile question to ask.

Comment: Thanks, WS2! I’m not personally a fan of bold or italics, but I can see how your use of both could be particularly helpful to other users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A candidate:

**[Lectures delivered before the American Institution of Instruction](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Lectures_Discussions_and_Proceedings/vz0rAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)**, Boston, August, **1841**,  pg 186

> The young should be prepared , by their education , to choose their rulers , and not be left in such ignorance as that the rulers shall choose their voters .

Comment: @AShelly While not strictly about gerrymandering, this is definitely the same general idea, and this is an old enough quote that I feel no qualms about accepting it.